# Equivalent in scala to java static method with type parameters

Tags: scala, generics

This is a cakewalk question: how to properly declare the T Type parameter in this object method Xforms.rotate?  Note it would not be my intention to provide type parameters to the object itself..

```
object Xforms {
  def rotate(data : Traversable[T]) = { }
}
```

For clarification I would be looking for a more or less equivalent of

```
public static <T> T rotate(T data) {
    T newData = null;
    // perform rotations on newData ..
    return newData;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Yes it is a straightforward question -as readily admitted in the OP. Is that not permitted on SOF?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the downvote is justified seeing as typing "scala method type parameter" into google gets you a page full of your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameters for a method come after the method name.

```
def rotate[T]( //...
```